# Having trouble running guessing game summary correctly

Tags: c++

I really hope I formatted this right. I've been working on this guessing game and it works pretty well. The only issue I have is with the `gameSummary` function. Instead of it adding up the efforts (say, 3 rounds played, 15 guesses at most in a round, 5 guesses at most for another round, with whatever average), it'll post the results of each game.

Example:

> ```
> Total number of rounds: 1
> The most number of guesses in one round: 10
> The least number of guesses in one round: 0
> Average number of guesses per round: -1.#IND
> Total number of rounds: 1
> The most number of guesses in one round: 5
> The least number of guesses in one round: 0
> Average number of guesses per round: -1.#IND
> ```

This also messes up the average because only one game was counted. I have a feeling `gameSummary(rounds, mostGuesses, leastGuesses, averageGuesses);` needs to be used, but I don't know exactly where I'm supposed to put it so that it counts results from the total games. Any ideas?

```
bool isTrue(int guess, int tries, int number, 
    int rounds, int mostGuesses, int leastGuesses, float averageGuesses)
{
    char answer;
    bool inGame = true; // states that the user is currently in the game
    while (inGame == true)
    {
        if (guess < 1 || guess > 99)
        {
            cout << "Invalid guess." << endl;
            cout << "Please take another guess: ";
            cin >> guess;
        }
        else
        {
            if (guess > number)
            {
                cout << "Lower please: ";
                cin >> guess;
                tries++;
            }
            else if (guess < number)
            {
                cout << "Higher please: ";
                cin >> guess;
                tries++;
            }
            else if (guess == number)
            {
                cout << "Congratulations! " << guess << " is the number!!\n";
                cout << "You guessed correctly in " << tries << " tries!!\n";
                inGame = false; // once the game is won, the while loop breaks.
                rounds++;
            }
            if (tries > mostGuesses)
            {
                mostGuesses = tries;
            }
            else if (tries < mostGuesses)
            {
                leastGuesses = tries;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "do you want to play another round? ";
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
    {
        game(); // replays the game if the user wants.
    }
    gameSummary(rounds, mostGuesses, leastGuesses, averageGuesses);
    return false;
}

void gameSummary(
    int rounds, int mostGuesses, int leastGuesses, float averageGuesses)
{
    cout << "Total number of rounds: " 
        << rounds << endl;
    cout << "The most number of guesses in one round: " 
        << mostGuesses << endl;
    cout << "The least number of guesses in one round: " 
        << leastGuesses << endl;
    cout << "Average number of guesses per round: " 
        << averageGuesses << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you count the number of `tries` for each round into, say `totalTries`, then the average will be `totalTries/rounds`. I hope you can complete your homework with this minimal hint. (BTW, there are other bugs in your code, but just presenting you with a completed solution will not help you learn.)

Comment: I made some changes to the code, basically the totalTries suggestion, yet I can't understand why, if I play two games, it runs through totalTries twice. Not even breakpoints could help me figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your function calls itself:

```
if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
{
    game(); // replays the game if the user wants.
}
gameSummary(rounds, mostGuesses, leastGuesses, averageGuesses);
```

I'm guessing that "game()" calls "isTrue()". So what happens is that when you answer 'Y', "game" is called and plays thru, summarizes the second game, and then returns back to the first invocation of isTrue, which then calls gameSummary().

See this [sscce](http://sscce.org/) live demo on ideone: http://ideone.com/oP5opZ

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void game(const std::string& from);

class PathTracker {
    std::string m_path;

public:
    PathTracker(const std::string& path_, const char* func_)
        : m_path(path_)
        {
            m_path += ">";
            m_path += func_;
            std::cout << m_path << " +enter+" << std::endl;
        }

    const std::string path() const { return m_path; }

    ~PathTracker() { std::cout << m_path << " -return-" << std::endl; }
};

void gameSummary(const std::string& from)
{
    PathTracker p(from, "gameSummary");
    std::cout << "[game summary]" << std::endl;
}

void isTrue(const std::string& from)
{
    PathTracker p(from, "isTrue");
    std::cout << "Another game? ";
    char answer;
    std::cin >> answer;
    std::cout << "Got " << answer << std::endl;
    if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y') {
        game(p.path());
    }
    gameSummary(p.path());
}

void game(const std::string& from)
{
    PathTracker p(from, "game");
    std::cout << "[get user input]" << std::endl;
    isTrue(p.path());
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    game("main");
}
```

I gave it an input of "Y" and "N" and the output is like this:

```
main>game +enter+
[get user input]
main>game>isTrue +enter+
Another game? Got Y
main>game>isTrue>game +enter+
[get user input]
main>game>isTrue>game>isTrue +enter+
Another game? Got N
main>game>isTrue>game>isTrue>gameSummary +enter+
[game summary]
main>game>isTrue>game>isTrue>gameSummary -return-
main>game>isTrue>game>isTrue -return-
main>game>isTrue>game -return-
main>game>isTrue>gameSummary +enter+
[game summary]
main>game>isTrue>gameSummary -return-
main>game>isTrue -return-
main>game -return-
```

When you responded "Y" the program detours into an INNER call to "game" which executes thru, calls gameSummary, and then returns back to where the code was before, which is right before the original call to "gameSummary" was about to happen.

The principle of recursion might be more simply demonstrated with this: http://ideone.com/sFk468

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int i)
{
    if (i == 0) {
        foo(1);
    }
    std::cout << "foo(" << i << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    foo(0);
}
```

Which outputs

```
foo(1)
foo(0)
```

Your code is repeating the same basic pattern.